# How do you get the vertex manipulator to show up in Blender 2.90?

Tags: modeling

I see in YouTube videos on blender that there is something called a manipulator. This allows for dragging and scaling on an axis. I cannot find this manipulator on my version of Blender. Here is a picture of what I am talking about:
[image]

How do I get that manipulator to show up in Blender 2.90?
This is the link to the video where I took this [screenshot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJkxGNW8JZU).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate the Move tool in the Toolbar :
[image]

Each tool have a specific manipulator.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a generic manipulator that is visible whenever another tool doesn't override it, if you want that.  You can find that under viewport settings - simply check the Active Object checkbox under Viewport Gizmos:

[image: viewport gizmos screenshot]